# Add assembly reference to Web Service

Tags: c#, assemblies, web-services

How do I configure a web service put in a IIS folder to reference a DLL that is not in the GAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the DLL as a dependency to the web service project. Then deploy the DLL alongside the rest of your web service DLL's.